# npm install apiconnect fails on macOS Catalina (v10.15.7)

Tags: node.js, apiconnect

I the Node.js package `apiconnect` will not install on my new MacBook Pro.  The Node.js version is `v10.22.1`, NPM version `6.14.6`, Python `3.8.3`

I ran the following command:

```
sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root --loglevel verbose apiconnect
```

The error that I receive is similar to what I received in the container (appmetrics@3.1.3).  The error from the log:

```
61922 silly install appmetrics@3.1.3
61923 info lifecycle appmetrics@3.1.3~install: appmetrics@3.1.3
61924 verbose lifecycle appmetrics@3.1.3~install: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
61925 verbose lifecycle appmetrics@3.1.3~install: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/apiconnect/node_modules/appmetrics/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/apiconnect/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.bin:/Users/steve/opt/anaconda3/bin:/Users/steve/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
61926 verbose lifecycle appmetrics@3.1.3~install: CWD: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/apiconnect/node_modules/appmetrics
61927 silly lifecycle appmetrics@3.1.3~install: Args: [ '-c', 'node extract_all_binaries.js || node-gyp rebuild' ]
61928 silly lifecycle appmetrics@3.1.3~install: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
61929 info lifecycle appmetrics@3.1.3~install: Failed to exec install script
61930 timing action:install Completed in 26347ms
61931 verbose unlock done using /Users/steve/.npm/_locks/staging-3a08f0df5026584d.lock for /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging
61932 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 8528ms
61933 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 468567ms
61934 verbose stack Error: appmetrics@3.1.3 install: `node extract_all_binaries.js || node-gyp rebuild`
61934 verbose stack Exit status 1
61934 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
61934 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:198:13)
61934 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
61934 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
61934 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
61934 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
61935 verbose pkgid appmetrics@3.1.3
61936 verbose cwd /Users/steve
61937 verbose Darwin 19.6.0
61938 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "--unsafe-perm=true" "--allow-root" "--loglevel" "verbose" "apiconnect"
61939 verbose node v10.22.1
61940 verbose npm  v6.14.6
61941 error code ELIFECYCLE
61942 error errno 1
61943 error appmetrics@3.1.3 install: `node extract_all_binaries.js || node-gyp rebuild`
61943 error Exit status 1
61944 error Failed at the appmetrics@3.1.3 install script.
61944 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
61945 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by changing the order of the directories in my `PATH` environment variable and running the install as `sudo` and using the `--unsafe-perm=true` and `--allow-root` options.

The full command used for the installation was:

```
sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root --loglevel verbose apiconnect
```

For the `PATH` environment variable, the installation of `anaconda3` Python/Jupyter Notebook package put their directories at the front of the path. By changing the path to so that:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:...
```

where the first directories in the path, the installation worked.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
npm i -g node-gyp@latest && npm config set node_gyp "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js"

node-gyp rebuild
```

Comment: The first command does but the `node-gyp rebuild` fails: `gyp: binding.gyp not found (cwd: /Users/steve) while trying to load binding.gyp`.